# How can I "register" a new help.txt document via .vimrc?

Tags: bash, vim

I am writing a bash script which installs and configures vim plugins, i.e. it creates a  new `.vimrc` and then echoes the config text into it.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

echo "installing Pathogen plugin manager"
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim

echo "installing ctrlp"
git clone https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim

cat << EOF >> ~/.vimrc

" vim settings
set number
set laststatus=2
syntax enable

"enable pathogen
execute pathogen#infect()

EOF
```

My problem is now how do I load the help file for `ctrlp`?
The [ctrlp homepage](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/) says to execute this command from *inside vim*

```
:helptags ~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/doc
```

I cant run the command from inside a bash script, so is it possible to load a directive into the `.vimrc` or how could I otherwise load this ctrlp help file into vim but **from a bash script?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using pathogen: just run `:Helptags` (please note the upper case `H`) once, when you're done installing all plugins.  After that you need to re-run it, again only once, whenever you update a plugin.  It's a command provided by pathogen, not the built-in `:helptags`.  You can run it from the command line:

```
vim -c Helptags -c q
```

Comment: works perfect thanks :) although Im trying to understand what is happening: is this correct? when `vim` command is run from the command line , either to launch the editor itself or to execute a command as in `vim -c` the pathogen script is executed/sourced - because it is in `~/vim/autoload` directory. the same occurs for the plugins in `bundle` at this point the pathogen `Helptags` function becomes available - and then run as per the `vim -c Helptags -c q` command? either way, thanks!

Comment: @user4668401: Yes, that's pretty much what is supposed to be going on.